# Output fonts, css files and other assets in a subdirectory of the dist folder

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, fonts

I'm following the guide on the official webpack website. For a reproducible code see [this section](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts) in the official website.

In the example provided, all the fonts are output under the dist folder. What I want is for the fonts to be output under a fonts subdirectory. Similarly for other types of assets such as css, images etc. I want them to be output under a folder depending on their extension.

The output would look something like this:

```
-/dist
--index.html
--bundle.js
--/css
---style1.css
--/fonts
---font1.woff
---font2.ttf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) to achieve that:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
    include: /images/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'images/',
          publicPath: 'images/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    include: /fonts/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'fonts/',
          publicPath: 'fonts/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Great, it worked. What is the include attribute for? Somehow it worked without it.

Comment: You can use `include` and `exclude` to filter the path e.g